# how to search and delete a series of attributs in html using vim?

Tags: html, regex, vim

i need help with vim and regex.

i have a html file with a lot of `class="..."`
e.g.

```
            <td class="td_3"><p class="block_3">80 €</p></td>
        <td class="td_3"><p class="block_3">90 €</p></td>
```

Since i'm not using any css, i want to delete them.
i tried:

:%s/class="[a-z0-9]"//g

but it's not working.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You match a single alnum char in between quotes. Use `:%s/\s*class="[^"]*"//g`

Comment: it works great! Thx! I'm new to regex. Would you pls explain?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `class="[a-z0-9]"` pattern, you match a single alphanumeric char in between quotes, while there may be any text other than double quotation mark.

You probably also want to remove the whitespaces before the `class`.

You may use

```
:%s/\s\+class="[^"]*"//g
```

Here, `\s\+` will match one or more whitespace chars, `class="` matches a literal string, then `[^"]*` finds any zero or more chars other than `"` as many as possible and then a `"` matches the closing double quotation mark.